# using Ultrasonic sensor to find obstecles Arduino

Tags: arduino

Am trying to make a smart cane for blind ppl using 2 ultrasonic sensors
to detect obstacles, and use a buzzer and a flat vibrating motor as a feedback when an obstacle is detected, where the flat motor should be ON when an obstacle
between 1m - 3m is detected, and the buzzer when it's less than 1m.
now recently i used the NewPing library which solved some of the problems but 
the code doesn't do exactly what i want, instead it triggers both the buzzer and motor together when object detected, i'd appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
#include <NewPing.h>

const int trigPin = 8;
const int trigPin1 = 13;
const int echoPin = 9;
const int echoPin1 = 12;
const int buzzer = 5;
const int motor = 3;

NewPing sonar1(trigPin,echoPin,maxout);
NewPing sonar2(trigPin1,echoPin1,maxout);


// defines variables
long duration;
long duration1;
int distance;
int distance1;


void setup() {

pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {


  distance = sonar1.ping_cm();
  distance1 = sonar2.ping_cm();


 if (distance > 100 || distance1 > 100) {
   digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);

   digitalWrite(motor,HIGH);

 }
 else if (distance <= 100 || distance1 <= 100) {

   digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(motor,LOW);



 }
  Serial.print("Distance1: ");
 Serial.println(distance); 
 Serial.print("Distance2: ");
 Serial.println(distance1); 


}
```

this is the ultrasonic pins:

first sensor (Vcc = 5V, trig = 8, echo = 9, GND = GND)

second sensor(Vcc = 5V, trig = 13 , echo = 12 , GND = GND)

and this is the buzzer and motor pins:

buzzer = 5 , GND

motor = 3 , GND

Answer (score 0):

Separate the logic for the motor and the buzzer:

```
if (distance >= 100 && distance <= 300) {
    // Motor on
    digitalWrite(motor, HIGH);
}
else {
    // Motor off
    digitalWrite(motor, LOW);
}

if (distance1 < 100) {
    // Buzzer on
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
}
else {
    // Buzzer off
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Mr. Johnny thanks for the quick reply, I have tried your solution, and now there's a reading from one sensor only, and the motor is not working also.